# YAHOO api geocode - What is the limit exceeded error code or ErrorMessage retrieved as a JSONObject?

Tags: json, limit, yahoo, geocode

I use Yahoo geocode api in an application for geocoding addresses and i need to log every time the geocoding limit is exceeded. Please tell me what error code or error message should i query, by parsing the JSONObject response.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see it, you get a "403 Forbidden" as a response when exceeding the rate limit. Additionally I get the following XML:

```
<?xml
    <Error>
        xmlns="urn:yahoo:api"
        The following errors were detected:\r\n\t\t
        <Message>
            limit exceeded
            </Message>
        </Error>
    <!-- ws05.ydn.ac4.yahoo.com uncompressed Tue Jun 28 07:56:13 PDT 2011 -->
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: what would the message look like in json?