# What is the limit exceeded error code or ErrorMessage retrieved as a JSONObject in yahoo api?

Tags: json, yahoo-api

I found this error [message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933971/yahoo-api-geocode-what-is-the-limit-exceeded-error-code-or-errormessage-retrei) for yahoo api when the limit is exceeded can anyone tell me what it would return as a Json object and not in xml format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder)

```
##
# Yahoo returns errors as XML even when JSON format is specified.
# Handle that here, without parsing the XML
# (which would add unnecessary complexity).
# Yahoo auth errors can also be cryptic, so add raw error desc
# to warning message.
#
def parse_raw_data(raw_data)
  if raw_data.match(/^<\?xml/)
    if raw_data.include?("Rate Limit Exceeded")
      raise_error(Geocoder::OverQueryLimitError) || warn("Over API query limit.")
    elsif raw_data =~ /<yahoo:description>(Please provide valid credentials.*)<\/yahoo:description>/i
      raise_error(Geocoder::InvalidApiKey) || warn("Invalid API key. Error response: #{$1}")
    end
  else
    super(raw_data)
  end
end
```

So it seems that you question cannot be answered because it will not return a jSON response from Yahoo API. It will always return XML format

Comment: hey do you have a code sample for php? would be appreciated

Comment: @vini unfortunately I don't write much php but it shouldn't be too hard to parse an XML response